# javascript onclick from array in order

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, onclick

I am making a YES/NO questionnaire that goes one question at a time and has a 'Next' button at the bottom of the question.

I want the Next button to cycle to the next question in the array with each click. How would I do this?

```
 <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="button"   onclick="nextQuestion()">Next</button>

    function nextQuestion(){
        document.getElementById("questionArea").innerHTML = ???,

}

var questionSet = new Array();
    questionSet[0] = "";
    questionSet[1] = "";  
    questionSet[2] = "";
    questionSet[3] = "";
```

Comment: Instead of changing the HTML, put all the HTML in the HTML in the document, in different DIVs. Then hide and show them by changing their `style.display`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add a var integer index and increase it on click next

```
 <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="button"onclick="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
var index_question = 0;
function nextQuestion(){
    document.getElementById("questionArea").innerHTML = questionSet[index_question];
    index_question ++;
}

var questionSet = new Array();
questionSet[0] = "";
questionSet[1] = "";  
questionSet[2] = "";
questionSet[3] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a data-* attribute on the button that holds the index, then in the click handler get the attribute and increment when needed.

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" 
        data-question="0" type="button"  
        onclick="nextQuestion(this)">Next</button>

function nextQuestion(btn){
    var index = (+btn.getAttribute("data-question"))+1;
    document.getElementById("questionArea").innerHTML = questionSet[index];
    btn.setAttribute("data-question",index);
}

var questionSet = new Array();
    questionSet[0] = "";
    questionSet[1] = "";  
    questionSet[2] = "";
    questionSet[3] = "";
```

And of course you will have to do checks to make sure not to go out of array bounds

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable and increase the value for each click:

```
var questionCount = 0;

function nextQuestion(){
questionCount++;
document.getElementById("questionArea").innerHTML = questionSet[questionCount];
}
```